# Apache2 and Flask issue

Tags: python, flask

I try to load my app towards my apache2 server but i keep getting error 500.

File Structure:
/var/www/ApproveAndPost:

- ApproveAndPost.wsgi
- ApprovePost_Web
- run.py

/var/www/ApproveAndPost/ApprovePost_Web:

- forms.py
- **init**.py
- models.py
- routes.py
- services.py
- static
- templates

Files content:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/ApproveAndPost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 192.168.170.67
                ServerAdmin email@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ApproveAndPost/ApproveAndPost.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/ApproveAndPost/ApprovePost_Web/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/ApproveAndPost/ApprovePost_Web/static
                <Directory /var/www/ApproveAndPost/ApprovePost_Web/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

WSGI File:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/ApproveAndPost")

from ApproveAndPost import app as application
application.secret_key = 'DISISSECRETKEY'
```

Python Code:

run.py

```
from ApprovePost_Web import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '#$%^&*'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from ApprovePost_Web import routes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I think i am mixing up a couple of things ?

Comment: You can check the logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to see what error you're getting

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is essentially that you are installing Flask, and possibly other required libraries, in a virtual environment but the python (wsgi interface) is running with the system python which does not have these extra libraries installed.

Comment: installed these without a virtual env to be sure but didnt fix it